# I used a BTC mining site and paid the fees but never got paid

Tags: fraud

[Where I paid mining fees and never got my BTC][1]

the transaction from my wallett shows 150 confirmations. I am new BTC can anyone help with this so i can understand WTF happened and am I just straight effed on the fees i paid. Thanks for your time help I appreciate it. I used the following site http://getbtc.online/dashboard/ one puts in the amount to be mined, the miners mine it and then you pay fee. Afterwards it should deposit the selected BTC amount in your wallet. Mine never got deposited in has several hundred confirmation and i know my wallet address is correct. The miners got paid; This is the site I get after I click on the confirmations in the wallet. I hope this is better as I stated previously; I am new to this and not sure WTF is going on. https://btc.blockr.io/tx/info/c842cc71b4f5133896a6302e208179400d57a79e885b617c4e21489e708fe2d1

Comment: Hi,
I've downvoted this question, because it is unclear what happened, how that differs from what you expected, and therefore especially what you're asking about in the first place. Besides that, the link is broken and it appears to have nothing to do with "transaction-fees". Please edit your question to give us a bit more to work with.

Comment: From the front page of the site: **"How it works our tool?"**
*Our software is a brand new tool that makes bitcoin mining more faster than any tool on the market.*.    That poor prose which does not actually provide information seems like a big warning sign.

Comment: Thread here. https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1819752.0

Comment: You fell for a scam.

Comment: You paid somebody to mine bitcoin, hoping that you will get more value from the bitcoin out than what you paid in, yes? Why would the person sell you the bitcoins at a lower rate, when they could just sell them themselves on the open market and make more money? This stinks of a blatant scam, it doesn't make sense..

Answer (score 2):

To give this a clear answer, so it can stop being bumped:

**You have been scammed.**

You are not going to get paid, and it is very unlikely you will be able to recover the money you have sent.  Accept that your money is lost, and don't send them any more.